# How to wrap or label all divs like files in opertaing systems (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I wrap all divs of HTML in this way that the `title` attributes of them gets labeled below just like files or directories in operating systems in CSS, JS or jQuery?

I am new to these so please I need a little explanation too.

*Example*:
http://rabwahnetwork.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Image.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `attr` function to get the title:

```
$(...).attr('title')
```

And jQuery's wrap function

```
$(...).wrap()
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/d9HtJ/